# Gimbal Sample Project (Mallmart) Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm trying to run example project (Mallmart) from gimbal https://www.gimbal.com/

Mallmart was successfully running, but when I tried to run Mallmart with IR I got this error

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "QCAR::State::getNumActiveTrackables() const", referenced from:
      -[EAGLView renderFrameQCAR] in ContextIR
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CMMotionManager", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libQCAR.a(libQCAR.a-armv7-master.o)
  "QCAR::State::getActiveTrackable(int) const", referenced from:
      -[EAGLView renderFrameQCAR] in ContextIR
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I tried to add libQCAR.a from vuforia-sdk-ios-2-0-29 but I still got this error

can somebody help me how to solve this problem?

sorry for my bad english, I hope you understand what I mean.

thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

On your project target **Build Settings** you should remove **armv7s** from the **Valid Architectures**.

It is most likely that *libQCAR.a* was not compiled for this architecture. By removing it from your project it will not try to compile your project in this architecture anymore and this should solve your problem.

Even you not compile for armv7s your app will still work on newer iOS device but it will not have all the optimizations for that architecture.